# How to log ddl commands on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I'm administrator of AgensGraph, and want to log all ddl.
Also, I want to know about that user who running ddl.

Is there good ideas about it?

Answer (score 0):

There is statement log on AgensGraph.

First, change parameters on "postgresql.conf"

```
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_line_prefix = '[%c] '
log_statement = 'ddl'
```

Second, restart AgensGraph.

```
$ ag_ctl stop
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
$ ag_ctl start
server starting
```

Finally, run ddl and check log file.

```
$ agens 
agens (AgensGraph 1.3.1, based on PostgreSQL 9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

agens =# create vlabel n;
CREATE VLABEL
agens=# \quit
```

Combination with connection log, you can get information who runs ddl.

```
[5c4573ae.f84] LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
[5c4573ae.f84] LOG:  connection authorized: user=agens database=agens
[5c4573ae.f84] LOG:  statement: create vlabel n;
[5c4573ae.f84] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:07.783 user=agens database=agens host=[local]
```